# Get users team leader and set value of the input field

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

First of all - I'm using an empty SharePoint site.

I would like to get the users team leader, to then put it as the value of the input [type=text].

```
<span>
    <label for="emailaddress">E-Mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="emailaddress" name="emailaddress" maxlength="120" size="50" required>
</span>
<span>
    <label for="teamLeader">Team Leader:</label>
    <input type="text" id="teamLeader" name="teamLeader" maxlength="120">
</span>
```

I've done this to get the email address of the user and to automaticly write it in the input field emailaddress, but I don't know if there's something like this to get the person responsible.

```
useremail = data.d.Email; $("#emailaddress").val(useremail);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to make the person input which works as SharePoint people control, you could use client people picker.

```
CustomPeoplePicker:
    <div id="peoplePickerDiv"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);
        })

        function sharePointReady() {
            context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            web = context.get_web();
            var schema = {};
            schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
            schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
            schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
            schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = true;
            schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
            schema['Width'] = '280px';

            var userIDs = "20;43";
            var userObjects = [];
            var userIDsSplit = userIDs.split(";");
            var DeferredCheck = 0;

            getUsers(context, userIDsSplit).done(function (_Users) {
                for (i = 0; i < _Users.length; i++) {
                    var defaultUser = new Object();
                    defaultUser.AutoFillDisplayText = _Users[i].get_title();
                    defaultUser.AutoFillKey = _Users[i].get_loginName();
                    defaultUser.Description = _Users[i].get_email();
                    defaultUser.DisplayText = _Users[i].get_title();
                    defaultUser.EntityType = "User";
                    defaultUser.IsResolved = true;
                    defaultUser.Key = _Users[i].get_loginName();
                    defaultUser.Resolved = true;
                    userObjects.push(defaultUser);
                    DeferredCheck++;
                    if (DeferredCheck == userIDsSplit.length) {
                        SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper('peoplePickerDiv', userObjects, schema);
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        function getUsers(context, userIDs) {
            var dfd = $.Deferred(function () {
                var users = [];
                for (j = 0; j < userIDs.length; j++) {
                    user = context.get_web().get_siteUsers().getById(userIDs[j]);
                    context.load(user);
                    users.push(user);
                }
                context.executeQueryAsync(
                    function () {
                        dfd.resolve(users);
                    }),
                    function () {
                        dfd.reject(args.get_message());
                    };
            });
            return dfd.promise();
        }
    </script>
```

[My demo thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/7911137d-4253-4fd7-932f-30e9359d56d3/binding-values-from-persongroup-column-from-splist-into-custom-people-picker-control-field?forum=onlineservicessharepoint)

Comment: I tried implementing this into my code but nothing happens. To be honest, I don't really understand everything that's written there, since I'm still not very knowledgeable in this field.
I adjusted my question to make my intentions clearer.